# Select the compiler of g++ between clang and gcc

Tags: macos, gcc, g++, clang, homebrew

I have installed gcc with brew and I have a Mac with Mojave. There is a way to compile with gcc or clang ? Because I use clang (is the default compiler) but sometimes I want to use gcc just saying `gcc hello world.cpp` instead of set the default compiler.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I choose to use alias in `.bash_profile`.

Homebrew will install `gcc` under `/usr/local/bin/`. If `which gcc` gives you `/usr/bin/gcc`, you are not using the gcc installed by brew.

See your installed version by

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/gcc*
```

Then create alias in `~/.bash_profile`

```
alias gcc='gcc-6'
alias cc='gcc-6'
alias g++='g++-6'
```